# Shopify update the inventory for the custom bundle

Tags: shopify

I am trying to create a bundle for the Shopify site. I do not want to use the Shopify app to create the bundle. Product A has 30 variants. A customer has to buy 6 quantity of variants at a time. It could be any 6 variants. How can I update the inventory for all the variants when the checkout is done?

Comment: The code will require the use of product properties and a few AJAX calls but without seeing any code from you side and what have you tried it will be hard to provide any help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't update inventory, Shopify updates inventory. Your job instead is to ensure the correct number of variants go into the checkout. If you have trouble with that, you can always help yourself out with some clever product manipulations. Another solution is to listen to the checkout and examine the products sold. You can then alter inventory levels to suit your needs.

Almost all the bundle Apps do the same thing. You can try them out and see if that squares your circle. I made one of the original bundlers whereby I had it so in a bundle, made of N products, the merchant could tag each variant for a specific quantity, and then the customer would be buying those specific quantities when buying the product. I would use Ajax calls to check quantity live, and when the product was purchased I would then deduct the right inventory quantities because the product itself had infinite quantity.

That was very sophisticated and worked most of the time, but completely messed up when customers would SIT on the cart. Inventory levels would change, and valid carts at the time would become stale, and inventory would be messed up, resulting in overselling stock. Me bad. Shopify bad. Bundling bad. With Shopify Plus, all that kind of went out the window, and bundles are much easier. Without Plus, you gamble!

Comment: I love answers with a good backstory like this one. I have been working with Plus for a over a year and had no idea it was better at bundling than the plain vanilla version, every thread I've ever seen on it the Shopify Staff just point users at 3rd party apps.

Comment: With Plus you can add, remove, and otherwise re-price bundles, so while it is not perfect, it does allow an expert to use Scripts to ensure things are better. And that takes into account inventory, so no overselling.

Comment: Thanks David, that's useful to know. My Ruby is absolutely rubbish so my Scripts so far have been pretty basic, really variations on the old official github examples and nothing ambitious. The limitation isn't really the syntax though, it's not having the vision to see what's possible so insight like this is good. Cheers!